# Errormessage uncomplete

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am trying to get errorinformation out of a powershell script. But the message is not complete it always sends back only a part of the massege.
This is the code:

```
 try
    {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $StandbyServer {powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file ("E:\Backup\SomeScript.ps1")} -ErrorAction Stop
    }

    catch [Exception]
    {
        .$SendEmail $_.Exception
        Write-Host $_.Exception
    }
```

the result looks like:

> System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Ausnahme beim Aufrufen
>   von "ExecuteScalar" mit 0 Argument(en):  "ALTER DATABASE

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the script file, but it's impossible to know exactly what without know what that script looks like.

Comment: Also, why are you shelling out from PowerShell to PowerShell? You could define the backup code (the content of `E:\Backup\SomeScript.ps1`) in a scriptblock in your script and run that scriptblock via `Invoke-Command` on the remote host.

Comment: Try looking at `$_.Exception.InnerException` and keep digging into `InnerException.InnerException` until it's null/empty. I usually find the last non-null value has a useful message.

Comment: If I remove the `-ErrorAction Stop` statement the exception is shown correctly